# Permission denied when chmod is set

Tags: permissions, groups, chgrp

Here is my problem:

I have created a group `allowed`

I have set it as primary-group for `user1` so after typing `groups` I see `allowed` as first one on the list.

I created directory via `sudo mkdir dir1` <- it has been created with `root` as owner and `root` as group (inside `ls -l`)

I have typed `sudo chgrp allowed dir1`  to change dir1's group

All files inside dir1 have been changed by `chmod 770 *`

but still I have no access to these files -> `ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied`

Is there anything I forget about?  How  to get access for users from the `allowed` group?
Of course, `chmod 777` is out of consideration...

Editing according to @Elder Geek

inside dir1

```
>ls -al gives:
>"ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied"


> sudo ls -al gives: 
> d-wx-wx---  2 root allowed   4096 mar  1 23:30 .
> drwxr-xr-x 24 root root      4096 mar  1 23:29 ..
> -rwxrwx---  1 root allowed    123 mar  1 23:30 excluded
> -rwxrwx---  1 root allowed  15964 mar  1 23:30 found inv.log
> -rwxrwx---  1 root allowed    220 mar  1 23:30 old.log
```

and from 1 level higher:

```
> ls -al di* (there is only 1 result for di*  -> dir1)
> ls: cannot open directory dir1: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the output of `ls -la dir1`

Comment: Is your user in the `allowed` group?  Also provide the output that @ElderGeek is looking for,

Comment: When did you start the current user session – before or after changing the primary user group? These changes are only applied upon the start of a new session.

Comment: Change to the directory above dir1 and provide us with the output of `ls -al` and as Thomas W. indicates are YOU in the allowed group?

Comment: Logout and login again, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> d-wx-wx---  2 root allowed   4096 mar  1 23:30 .
> ```

That directory doesn't have read permissions for anybody (that's why only root can list contents). Give read access:

```
sudo chmod ug+r dir1
```